# Fetching an array in php

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a php script to obtain the biography of a musical group. The resulting JSON has a property named "musicians" which must be a list of musicians.
I do like this:

```
$group["musician"] = mysqli_fetch_array($group["nombre_musico"]." ".$group[apellidos_musico].", ");
```

where:

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bd_tfg");
```

and:

```
$sql = "select gr.nombre_grupo, gr.anyo_creacion, gr.descripcion, ms.nombre_musico, ms.apellidos_musico\n"
. "from musico ms, canta_para cp, grupo gr\n"
. "where ms.id_musico = cp.musico_id and gr.id_grupo = cp.grupo_id and gr.nombre_grupo = \'oreja van gogh\'";
```

I hope for a little help to perform this.

Comment: Read the php manual about mysql_fetch_array(). It doesn't do what you think it does. http://ch1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Your Question is lacking the *Question!*

Comment: How is a JSON resulted here?

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute the query after your mysqli_connect, and then fetch the values... something like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bd_tfg");
$sql = "..."; (your query)
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$group = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

And then, you can do, if you like:

```
$group["musician"] = $group["nombre_musico"]." ".$group["apellidos_musico"];
```